# C# Wait for SendKeys to finish sending keystrokes before executing next line of code (no app.config file)

Tags: c#, sendkeys

So previously, in order to make sure SendKeys.SendWait completed sending keystrokes before continuing, you could add something to the app.config file. This is documented here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/input-keyboard/how-to-simulate-events?view=netdesktop-5.0

However, with .Net Core/ .Net 5, there is no app.config file. What's the best way to do this now?

Comment: I believe, for backward compatibility, you can add a app.config yourself - not sure if the call will work though.

Comment: From what I understand - adding an app.config is just there for backwards compatibility, but the values aren't used

Comment: Why not just put your own small delay in?

Comment: This is what I'm currently doing. However, a delay isn't foolproof. When the input you're sending is variable, the longer the SendKeys input is, the more chance it is interrupted before it has a chance to finish. Also things like memory can delay SendKeys.